# to_timestamp/unix_timestamp is unable to parse string datetime to timestamp in spark for daylight saving datetime

Tags: apache-spark, datetime, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, dst

I am using spark 2.4 and using the below code to cast the string datetime column(`rec_dt`) in a dataframe(`df1`) to `timestamp(rec_date`) and create another dataframe(`df2`).

All the datetime values are getting parsed correctly except for the values where there are daylight saving datetime values.

The time zone of my session is `'Europe/London'` and I do not want to store the data as UTC time zone and finally I have to write data as `'Europe/London'` time zone only.

```py
spark_session.conf.get("spark.sql.session.timeZone")
# Europe/London
```

Code :

```py
df2 = df1.withColumn("rec_date", to_timestamp("rec_dt","yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss"))
```

output :

[image]

Please help.

Comment: I see that the `format` string you have given in the question does not conform to the input. Can you confirm you still see `None` values with the correct format strings?

Comment: Yes I still see None values with correct format string 'only' for the datetime when the daylight saving occured example: last Sunday of March